# Commit notes to display changes made in code

Tags: git, visual-studio, bitbucket, bitbucket-server, team-explorer

I am using Team Explorer in Visual Studios and have linked my BitBucket account up with it and can quite happily make changes to my code and Commit/Push/Sync those up to show on the BitBucket site.

However, it's been tasked of me that I find a way, that when making changes, the Change comments that can be made before Pushing/Syncing show automatically the changes that have been made in the code, which become the comment itself. I have looked but can't find a way. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: "Change comments that can be made before Pushing/Syncing" the VS display of a commit will show the comments and allow you to see all the code changes (the tool Window lists the file changes, double click to show a diff).

Comment: Ah, yes, that's quite handy. I do wonder though, if there's a way to automated the said code changes to automatically populate the in the Comments box though. Seems to be the sticking point

Comment: Putting all the code changes in the comment kind of misses the point of the way Git works. ` git show <commit>` will show a diff (because the commit object links to the previous commits and a snapshot of all the files), a `git log` with the appropriate format options can do this over many commits.

Comment: That's a fair point. I personally think I could look a bit messy if I was to be able to do it this way, but thought i'd ask. Thanks for confirming my own thoughts on this.